# "Unable to find any mappings for the given content, keyPath=null" RestKit 0.2

Tags: ios6, restkit

So I switched to using RestKit 0.2 and CoreData and I've been having a lot of trouble trying to get the mappings correct... I don't understand why. The JSON Response of my server is like this:

```
{
"meta": 
   {
   "limit": 20, 
   "next": null, 
   "offset": 0, 
   "previous": null, 
   "total_count": 2
   }, 
   "objects": 
   [{
       "creation_date": "2012-10-15T20:16:47", 
       "description": "", 
       "id": 1, 
       "last_modified": 
       "2012-10-15T20:16:47", 
       "order": 1, 
       "other_names": "", 
       "primary_name": "Mixing",
       "production_line": "/api/rest/productionlines/1/", 
       "resource_uri": "/api/rest/cells/1/"
   }, 
   {
       "creation_date": "2012-10-15T20:16:47", 
       "description": "",
       "id": 2, 
       "last_modified": "2012-10-15T20:16:47",
       "order": 2, "other_names": "", 
       "primary_name": "Packaging", 
       "production_line": "/api/rest/productionlines/1/",
       "resource_uri": "/api/rest/cells/2/"
   }]
}
```

Then in XCode I have:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;


RKEntityMapping *cellMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Cell" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
cellMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"identifier";
[cellMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id": @"identifier",
 @"primary_name": @"primaryName",
 }];



RKResponseDescriptor *responseCell = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:cellMapping
                                                                             pathPattern:@"/api/rest/cells/?format=json"
                                                                                 keyPath:@"objects"
                                                                             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[responseCell, responseUser, responseCompany]];


[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppDB.sqlite"];
NSString *seedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeedDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedPath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

My request is:

```
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/rest/cells/?format=json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        RKLogInfo(@"Load complete: Table should refresh...");

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LastUpdatedAt"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Load failed with error: %@", error);
    }];
```

And I always get the following error:

```
**Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "Unable to find any mappings for the given content" UserInfo=0x1102d500 {DetailedErrors=(), NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to find any mappings for the given content, keyPath=null}**
```

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**: I have added     cellMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
but still no luck :(!

***UPDATE #2***: Following Blake's advice, I tried to change the path and it worked! I did /api/rest/cells/ instead of /api/rest/cells/?format=json and my server returned me everything and the mapping was successful!

Now the only problem I get is the following error:

**2012-11-21 14:48:49.414 App[3125:617] W restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:176 Collection mapping forced but mappable objects is of type '__NSCFArray' rather than NSDictionary**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the response descriptor is failing to match for the URL requested. Two ideas:

1. Try removing the path pattern entirely (pass in nil) and just using a key-path based match on 'cells'
2. Try using a path pattern of '/api/rest/cells'

The next thing I would try is using the debugger to step through the matching. Within `RKObjectManager` a list of candidate response mapping is built by the `RKFilteredArrayOfResponseDescriptorsMatchingPath` function. If your expected response mapping is not being returned in there, then the request path to path pattern is failing to evaluate.

If things look good there, the next place a mismatch could occur is in `RKResponseMapperOperation` within the `buildResponseMappingsDictionary` method. This method evaluates the response against each response descriptor. If the response is failing to match against your response descriptor, then you'll get unexpected results here.

The final place to check is within RKResponseMapperOperation. This takes the mappings from matched descriptors and applies them. The RKMapperOperation `main` method should contain the deserialized response you expect and the appropriate mappings on the `mappingsDictionary` property.

Comment: I followed your advice and then removed the line about force mapping that I had and it worked! Thanks again Blake!

Answer (score 0):

Even when the setup seems to be right, the mapping is wrong. The information your mapping is calling is nested inside the given objects, so you've to tell the mapping to look up the values inside of the objects.

```
RKEntityMapping *cellMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Cell" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
cellMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"identifier";

[cellMapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"objects"];
[cellMapping mapFromKeyPath:@".id" toAttribute:"identifier"];
[cellMapping mapFromKeyPath:@"primary_name" toAttribute:"primaryName"];
```

For more information check the [RKObjectMapping Reference](http://restkit.org/api/development/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html).

Comment: The thing is that the function mapFromKeyPath is only in RKObjectMapping... and I am using CoreData. Hence, I have a RKEntityMapping and mapFromKeyPath is not in RKEntityMapping.

Comment: I'm updating to RestKit 0.20 next week so I'll let you know what I found out about the process of configurate the mapping over there. My advice: Use the master branch (10.3) if the project is urgent because 0.20 is under heavy development.